# How can I resize table column width while designing Maximo anywhere app

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I have tried using usefieldsizegroup="false" and then setting width and size values , however the column width are not getting adjusted.

Comment: did you try adjusting each table column manually... or trying width in the first entry of table trying `width=1000` for example?

Answer (score 1):

I think that flag tells maximo to not use the default field sizes based on field types (text box, table column, text editor, etc...). At least that's how I took their documentation:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21388710

I was able to resize table column fields in Maximo (didn't try Anywhere-Maximo) by using a 'width' flag in the XML like so:

```
<tablecol dataattribute="CHANGEDATE" id="11111111111" label="Change Date" width="120"/>
```

Comment: Width comment works for individual table column, I was trying to resize the full table into a smaller viewport and in that case width dint help

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the layout which is associated with the listItemTemplate  element of your list. For example we want to change the width of the text field on position item3:

```
<listItemTemplate id="xxxxx" layout="WorkListItem">
 <listtext layoutInsertAt="item3"
```

In this example You can find this layout template at /apps//artifact/layouts/templates/small/WorkListItem.xml

When you open this file you will see the definition of your list layout. Search the "item3" place in the layout. By editing the colspan attribute you can manipulate tablecol width:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <layout id="WorkListItem" width="100">
  <row id="row_0">
   <column colspan="10" columnid="item3" id="item3_column"/>
   <column colspan="2" columnid="button1" halign="right" id="button1_column" rowspan="3"/>
</row>
 <row id="row_1">
     <column colspan="8" columnid="item1" id="item1_column"/>
     <column colspan="2" columnid="item2" id="item2_column"/>
 </row>
 <row id="row_2">
    <column colspan="5" columnid="item4" id="item4_column"/>
    <column colspan="5" columnid="item5" id="item5_column"/>
 </row>
</layout>
```

Comment: thank you . looks like this works for Maximo Anywhere , but I was looking for similar functionality in Maximo Everyplace